# Linux/bash: Change key category codes within script

Tags: linux, bash, categories

I have a very simple script that's essentially an alias for `find -iname`, so I can find the path to a file whose name I sort of remember , but whose location I've definitely forgotten. I'd type `myscript *cri*unis*`, for example, to quickly locate `crime_and_punishment.txt`.

But now I am getting rather lazy about pressing the shift key to enter the wildcard character, so I'd like to make `,` be the wildcard character only when parsing the input parameters to my script.

It's similar to if I were using TeX and had to type a long table and wanted to temporarily make `,` be the column delimiter: I would type **\bgroup \catcode`\,=4** and then enter **\egroup** when finished with my table.

And come to think of it, how do I enter a back-tick within an inline code snippet on this site's markdown?! The markdown should let me temporarily use `;` to delimit an inline code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure I understand the question but if you would like to replace all `,` characters in the input with `*` characters. Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

search=`echo "$1" | tr "," "*"`

find -iname "$search"
```

Comment: Please no! use `search=${1//,/*}` instead.